# Software to build a graphic which describes the program

Tags: mind-mapping

I´m looking for a program or any (maybe mindmap tool) to make my program a bit visual. So that you can see my functions and the files in which are these function and which relation they have.

Maybe there´s something like this availible?

Thank you!

Comment: On what OS should it run? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Answer (score 2):

There was a big effort in the late 1990s and early 2000s called [UML - Unified Modeling Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

Please open the Wikipedia article that I've linked to, scroll down to see examples of various types of diagrams or visualiations.

However UML it has become less popular over the years. You can't use these diagrams to demonstrate (let alone prove) that  programs run correctly, and drawing these diagrams  is often considered time wasted that should be spent on gathering requirements or writing tests instead. (I slightly disagree).

There are many free and commercial UML tools available s, and questions for those have been asked [many times here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=UML+is%3AQ) on Softwarerecs.SE.

Business Process Model and Notation [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) is another visualisation- or modeling technique, more targeted at workflows, but there exists more of a culture of verification and automatic checking of things.   Diagrams are prettier though ;-)